# how to add checkmark in UISwitch control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hello everyone i am trying to add a checkmark on UISwitch control. I do not know where to start. Any help appreciated. Result should be like the image below. Actually i have already an implementation without the checkmark but i need to add the checkmark somehow.

[image]

Comment: Add a view with the checkmark... disable user interaction on it... show/hide it based on the switch state.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't do it with `UISwitch`. Before iOS 7 you used to be able to set on/off images, but those properties are [now](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch/1623689-onimage) [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch/1623683-offimage). If yo don't like the default styling, you have a few options:

- You could add a floating image on top of the UISwitch like @DonMag suggested. This is probably the easiest way to go, but might not end up with the exact visual treatment you want.
- You can use use a `UISegmentedControl` or a `UIButton`. Both of those classes have ways to set custom images for different states. `UIButton` is likely simpler to customize than `UISegmentedControl`.
- You can build your own `UIControl` or use an open source custom control (i.e. from Cocoapods, or other source). Going open source will be easier than building your own.